# Python generator vs comprehension and pass by reference vs value

Tags: python, oop, list-comprehension

I have some code that iterates over a string and produces a list of objects from the string, which I'm calling an instance. It looks something like this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class MyInstance:
    data = defaultdict(str)

    def __init__(self, data, parser):
        # parse the input
        self.parser = parser


class MyParser:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        data = data.split('\n\n')
        self.instances = (MyInstance(instance, self) for instance in data)


mydata = # ... coming in from stdin or file
parser = MyParser(mydata)
```

This was working fine, but then I realized I needed to check my instances more than once. So, I figured I would just changed my generator to a list comprehension:

```
self.instances = [MyInstance(instance, self) for instance in data]
```

Which allows me to iterate over my instances as many times as a want, but all of a sudden, all of the instances are the same. When I print out the data just before this line, each instance is unique. However, after the list comprehension, they are all the same.

```
class MyParser:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        data = data.split('\n\n')
        print data
        self.instances = (MyInstance(instance, self) for instance in data)
        print list(self.instances)
```

prints...

```
['the soldier sleeps', 'the big soldier sleeps', 'the big wonderful soldier sleeps']
['the big wonderful soldier sleeps', 'the big wonderful soldier sleeps', 'the big wonderful soldier sleeps']
```

However, the strangest part is that when I tried to recreate this issue using similar code to the above, **I couldn't replicate it**:

```
class myClass:

  def __init__(self, i):
    self.i = i

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.i)


instances = [myClass(i) for i in range(3)]
print instances

instances = (myClass(i) for i in range(3))
print list(instances)
```

prints...

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
```

I checked to see if the memory address of each instance (in the broken code) was the same or different, and it looks like they are different... (though I admit I'm not sure if this means anything)

```
for i in self.instances:
  print id(i) # 4463026760, 4463026544, 4463026616
```

So, I have no idea what's going on. Any suggestions of why these instances seem to be linked?

Comment: MyInstance constructor is defined with only one parameter `data`, what it the `self` in `MyInstance(instance, self)` ? I think the problem is in the `MyInstance` class ...

Comment: In Python 2.x you should inherit from `object`, and you should be creating `MyInstance(instance)`

Comment: Serge, sorry I forgot to include/exclude that parameter from my example. I have edited the myInstance to reflect this pointer back to the parser.

Comment: funny thing, I cannot reproduce your bug even with your 'broken' code. You sure that is all the code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks for the reminder. I have updated my code to inherit from object. However, this doesn't fix the problem -_-

Comment: Please update your question to include an actual [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - from what you've posted, there is not sufficient information to diagnose a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue has to do with how I was initiating my data. I was initiating a defaultdict as a member of the class:

```
class myClass:
    self.data = defaultdict(str)

    def __init__(self, data):
        for i, instance in enumerate(data.split('\n')):
            # Do something...
            self.data[i] = instance
```

I changed it to this:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = defaultdict(str)
        for i, instance in enumerate(data.split('\n')):
            # Do something...
            self.data[i] = instance
```

And that fixed my problem. Would be interested to hear if anyone knows why.