# What's the correct way to pass by reference

Tags: python

I have seen other people ask a question but the only answers I have seen simply explain that python doesn't have the same concept of pass by reference vs pass by value as languages like C do.
for example

```
    x=[0]
    def foo(x):
        x[0] += 1
```

In the past, I have been using this work around but it seems very un-pythonic so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.
let's assume for what ever reason returning values won't work, like in the case where this code runs on a separate thread.

Comment: It's not that you cannot [technically hack Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45113210/7553525) to always 'pass by reference', tho. btw. Python always passes by reference in those terms (_reference_ is a vague concept when it comes to Python), it's just that certain properties are mutable and others are not - non-mutable properties utilize copy-on-write, tho, so you get the illusion they weren't passed by reference.

Comment: Python uses "pass by object", so neither pass by reference or value are applicable. You can use techniques like generators also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034395/python-generator-vs-comprehension-and-pass-by-reference-vs-value

Comment: This looks like an [`XY problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to pass anything by reference, you need an [atomic counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088370/6419007).

Comment: @EricDuminil sorry, This is not an XY problem, I only included that code to help illustrate the problem. I am somewhat new to SO and if you have an idea on how to better ask the question so this distinction is more apparent please edit

Comment: There is no pass by reference. Did you think the people who told you Python doesn't support pass by reference were lying to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some python objects are immutable (`tuple`, `int`, `float`, `str`, etc). As you have noted, you cannot modify these in-place.

The best workaround is to *not* try to fake passing by reference, instead you should assign the result. This is both easier to read and less error prone.

In your case, you could call:

```
x = 0
def f(x):
    return x + 1

x = f(x)
```

If you truly need to fake passing by reference (and I don't see why you would need that), your solution works just fine, but keep in mind that you do not actually modify the object.

```
x = 0
x_list = [x]
print(id(x_list[0]))  # 1844716176

def f(x_list):
    x_list[0] += 1

f(x_list)
print(x)  # 0,  not modified
print(id(x_list[0]))  # 1844716208
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve returning values. I edited the question to reflect this

Comment: The problem is that any solution that does not involve returning values is un-pythonic and basically a hack.

Comment: the real use case is trying to share a variable between two threads, so if you have a better idea that would help

Comment: @JonasAdler: This looks Pythonic to me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088370/6419007

Comment: How is that link relevant? There is no function call.

Comment: According to the last sentence in the question and the comment above, the OP isn't interested in pass by reference, he only needs a thread-safe counter.